# Como deixar um radiobutton marcado como padrão no ember

Tags: formulário, radiobutton, emberjs

Tenho esses dois components `radio-button`. Gostaria de deixar a `Pessoa Física` marcado/checked como padrão. Como faço isso no EmberJS ?.

```
<div>
  <label>Pessoa Física</label>
  {{radio-button
    id="classificacao-pessoa-is-fisica"
    radioClass="classificacao-pessoa-is-fisica" 
    groupValue=classificacao.pessoa.tipo
    value='FISICA'
  }}
</div>
<div  class="col-sm-12 text-right">
  <label>Pessoa Jurídica</label>
  {{radio-button
    id="classificacao-pessoa-is-juridica"
    radioClass="classificacao-pessoa-is-juridica"
    groupValue=classificacao.pessoa.tipo
    value='JURIDICA'
  }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta adicionar a propriedade `classificacao` no seu controller ou component

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  .
  .
  .
  classificacao: {
    pessoa: {
      tipo: 'FISICA'
    }
  }
});
```

Veja o exemplo em: https://ember-twiddle.com/8c560f0b5b75ca5308ca138ed694c414?numColumns=2&openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2Ctemplates.application.hbs

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo usando isso

Answer (score 0):

Tenta adicionar

```
checked="checked"
```

apenas no radio que vc quer

Comment: nao da certo, aparece um erro no console, consegui definir valor default no javascript somente